# C++ Virtual classes basic questions

Tags: c++, class, programming-languages, virtual

1. Is there any difference between `virtual public` & `public virtual`? If yes, then why?
2. Why are all classes not virtual?

Example:

```
class x { 
   protected: int a; 
};

class y : public virtual x {  
   protected: int b; 
};
```

Comment: Answer to 2: There's a performance hit to using virtual classes. Each virtual class has the overhead of storing a virtual function table which non-virtual classes don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand difference between virtual and non-virtual inheritance check (and try to understand) the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base { 
       int a; 
};

struct D11 :    virtual Base    {};
struct D12 :    virtual Base    {};
struct D21 :    Base    {};
struct D22 :    Base    {};

struct E1: D11, D12 {
    std::pair<int, int> func(int i1, int i2){
        dynamic_cast<D11*>(this)->a = i1;
        dynamic_cast<D12*>(this)->a = i2;
        return std::pair<int, int>(dynamic_cast<D11*>(this)->a, dynamic_cast<D12*>(this)->a);
    }
};

struct E2: D21, D22 {
    std::pair<int, int> func(int i1, int i2){
        dynamic_cast<D21*>(this)->a = i1;
        dynamic_cast<D22*>(this)->a = i2;
        return std::pair<int, int>(dynamic_cast<D21*>(this)->a, dynamic_cast<D22*>(this)->a);
    }
};

int main(){
    E1 e1;
    E2 e2;
    std::pair<int, int>  p1, p2;
    p1 = e1.func(1,2);
    p2 = e2.func(3,4);
    cout << "p1: " << p1.first << ", " << p1.second << endl; // Will return p1: 2, 2
    cout << "p2: " << p2.first << ", " << p2.second << endl; // will return p2: 3, 4
    return 0;
}
```

It's easier to understand if you imagine it like that:
[image]

Sometimes it's nice to have possibility of storing different values of variables in different bases. Sometimes the opposite. C++ let you choose.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no difference between `public virtual` and `virtual public`, they are two unrelated specifiers (one determines the visibility of the inheritance relationship, the other determines whether the relationship is virtual or not) that can be swapped freely.

There are semantic differences between inheritance being virtual or not (if D inherits from B and C, which both inherit from A, then virtual inheritance means only one instance of A will be present and shared by both B and C, and non-virtual inheritance means two instances will be present). Sometimes, you want one instance, sometimes you want two. The language designers had to pick a default, and non-virtual inheritance was chosen, so you need to explicitly ask for virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Is there a difference between const int and int const? no.
2.) Classes with virtual functions are called polymorphic classes. I suggest you to read here:
http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/51645

Comment: There is a difference between `int const*` and `int* const` ;-) Also, the question is related to virtual **inheritance**, not virtual functions. Pre-emptive comment: virtual inheritance are an actual C++ concept related to multiple inheritance, look it up.

Comment: thank you for the first answer. But you haven't answered my second question. I have read about virtual classes already so i want to know why aren't all classes virtual ? Why aren't classes virtual by default ? Why do we need to write virtual ? Isn't virtual much better ?

Comment: @Victor I thought he meant virtual functions. @ropio You're basically asking the same thing. Why isn't everything virtual by default? Well, because you only use it when you need it. There are certain uses for such things. This link should help you: http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_virtual_inheritance_and_how_is_it_used%3F

Comment: the thing is i don't usually trust only few links, i want to hear it from other people that work with this also.

Answer (score 0):

1. No as far as I remember. But following convention is prefered (reference: MSDN)

   virtual [type-specifiers] member-function-declarator

   virtual [access-specifier] base-class-name
2. Following link has a good explaination of the example you listed above http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html

For novice C++ programmers, http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/index.html#table-of-contents serves as one of the good reference point

Comment: I have read about virtual classes, so i want to know why do we need to write virtual if virtual is much better, why do we even have without virtual ?

Comment: @ropio Could you please elaborate on your comment? Have you read [25.8] What is the "dreaded diamond"? in the link I provided - it answers why you need virtual classes.

Comment: Also 'virtual' adds a small cost to overall performance. Please see for more technical insight of how virtual functions work http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html

Comment: that link doesn't explain any performance penalty to virtual inheritance really.

Comment: @matt sorry, my comment was a bit ambiguos. those were two indepenent statements there:( I provided the link for reading some of the technical aspect about how virtual functions work and this is not related to performance.